# Concatenate node names recursively

Tags: sql, recursion, firebird, recursive-query, firebird2.1

I'm using Firebird 2.1 and I have the following hierarchical table:

```
NodeID, ParentNodeID, Name
```

ParentNodeID = -1 for root nodes.

For example:

```
1, -1, Parent
2, 1, Child
3, 2, Child of child
```

I'm looking for a recursive query (or stored procedure) to output a concatenation the following way:

```
Parent
Parent - Child
Parent - Child - Child of child
```

Siblings should be sorted in alphabetic order. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a stored procedure:

```
create procedure tree (root integer) returns (result varchar(1000)) as
  declare id integer;
  declare n varchar(30);
  declare childs varchar(1000);
begin
  for select NodeId, Name from t where ParentNodeId = :root order by Name into :id, :result do
   begin
    suspend;
    n = result;
    for select result from tree(:id) into :childs do
      begin
        result = n || ' - ' || childs;
        suspend;
      end
   end
end
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/_fY5xZS6

In Firebird 2.1 and newer you could also use a recursive CTE.

Comment: Recursive CTEs are available since Firebird 2.5, not 3.0, I edited your answer to reflect that.

Comment: I believe it's available from Firebird 2.1 onwards:
https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb210-cte

Comment: @Steve Seems like you're right :)

Comment: @Steve I posted an answer that shows the solution with a recursive CTE. I hope you realise that Firebird 2.1 went out of support back in December 2014, you should really consider upgrading.

Comment: Thank you, I also edited the original answer to reflect it's supported from 2.1 on.

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this with a recursive CTE in Firebird 2.1:

```sql
with recursive t as (
  select nodeid, name
  from relation
  where parentnodeid = -1
  union all
  select r.nodeid, t.name || ' - ' || r.name
  from t
  inner join relation r on r.parentnodeid = t.nodeid
)
select name
from t;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/VBJ3B8Ka

If you need to order siblings by name, you can add an `order by name` to the top-level select.